# Strange behaviour of WebView

Tags: android, webview

I faced with strange behaviour of the WebView.

I have an Activity with a WebView. Layout also contains layout with VideoView and paceholders:
- app starts, WebView loads content from the internal storage
- user clicks on a link, app shows a VideoView (View.GONE -> View.VISIBLE)

I works well till user leave app via BACK and starts again:
- app starts, WebView loads content from the internal storage
- user clicks on a link, app try to show a VideoView (View.GONE -> View.VISIBLE) but nothing happened

I have tried to avoid VideoView to find a cause of provlem, just show\hide view, but problems the same. I check it via debugger, container is trully visible but it doesn't shown. I have tried to dismiss WebView - it still on the device screen, issue in the WebView

Do you have any ideas what is going on here?

Comment: Hard to say without code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved issue. Seems it is an issue in the legacy code, some kind of leak that blocks me. Quick fix is tp use System.exit(1) instead on finish on overrided back press